# How to refresh props with React/Redux when user enters a container

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have CompetitionSection which repeats all the competitions from database. When user clicks on one, it redirects him to a Competition Page, loads for a second and renders the page with all the details in it. So far, so good.

But when users goes back to the Competition Section and then click on the second competition, it instantly loads up the previous competition, 0 loading time.

From my point of view, what is failing is that the props of the component are not updating when I render the component (from the second time). Is not a router problem, which was my first instinct because I'm seeing the route.params changing acordingly, but the actions I dispatch to change the props are not dispatching. Here's a bit of code of said component.

```
class CompetitionPage extends React.Component {

componentWillMount() {
  let id = getIdByName(this.props.params.shortname)
  this.props.dispatch(getCompAction(id));
  this.props.dispatch(getCompMatches(id));
  this.props.dispatch(getCompParticipants(id));
  this.props.dispatch(getCompBracket(id));
}

render() {   
 let { comp, compMatches, compBracket, compParticipants } = this.props
 ...
```

I tried every lifecycle method I know. component Will/Did Mount, component Will/Did update and I even set shouldUpdate to true and didn't do the trick. As I understand, the problem will be solved with a lifecycle method to dispatch the actions everytime an user enters Competition Page and not just for the first time. I'm running out of options here, so any help will be appreciated.

NOTE: I'm a newbie at React/Redux so I KNOW there are a couple of things there are anti-pattern/poorly done.

UPDATE: Added `CompetitionsSection`

```
 class CompetitionsSection extends React.Component {

   render() {
       const {competitions} = this.props;   
       return (
           ...
           { Object.keys(competitions).map(function(comp, i) {
           return ( 
               <div key={i} className={competitions[comp].status === 
               undefined? 'hide-it':'col-xs-12 col-md-6'}>
               ...
               <Link to={"/competitions/"+competitions[comp].shortName}>
                   <RaisedButton label="Ver Torneo" primary={true} />
               </Link>
               ...
```

Comment: Can you post your `CompetitionSection` code? My initial guess is that your `CompetitionPage` is just updating, not unmounting / remounting, but I'd have to see the code to be sure

Comment: Did you try `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`? Maybe there is no update here...

Comment: @taylorc93 how to make sure that `CompetitionPage` unmount/remound the component? I'll update the question and add some more bits of code.

Comment: @Brejk I did try that with no results

Answer (score 0):

It helps to better understand the lifecycle hooks. Mounting a component is when it is placed on the DOM. That can only happen once until it is removed from the DOM. An UPDATE occurs when new props are passed or setState is called. There are a few methods to troubleshoot when updates are not happening when you think they should:

1. **Ensure that you are changing state in componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate**. You cannot trigger an update in componentWillMount.
2. **Make sure that the new props or state are completely new objects**. If you are passing an object down in props and you are just mutating the object, it will not trigger an update. For instance, this would not trigger a update:

```js
class CompetitionPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      competitions: [ compA, compB ]
    }
  }

  triggerUpdate() {
    this.setState({
      competitions: competitions.push(compC)
    })
  }

componentDidMount() {
  triggerUpdate()
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is due to the fact that a new competition is being appended to the array in state. The correct way is to completly create a new state object and change what needs to be changed:

```js
const newCompetitions = this.state.competitions.concat(compC)

this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, { competitions: newCompetitions }))
```

3. **Use ComponentWillRecieveProps on an update to compare previous and current prop values.** You can setState here if clean up needs to be done:

Read more about this method in the React documentation:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: `Ensure that you are changing state in componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate.` It won't work because I get this data from `this.props` and they don't update, so I think the problem is before this point.




`Make sure that the new props or state are completely new objects` How do I do that though? I'm not passing props down to another component, I'm just routing to a new component and once there I make the call and dispatch actions (with route.params) to get what I need.



`Use ComponentWillRecieveProps on an update to compare previous and current prop values` This didn't work